# Call to undefined function post() in

Tags: php, mysql

I have defined the functions at top but now got this error

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare post() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\SPdealer\Admin Panel\Property_Insertion_Files\Customers Online Property_Insert_Page_exe .php:4) in C:\xampp\htdocs\SPdealer\Admin Panel\Property_Insertion_Files\Customers Online Property_Insert_Page_exe .php on line 15"

Here is the code:

```
    <?php
     $moreaboutgeneralinfo = post('moreaboutgeneralinfo');

     function post($moreaboutgeneralinfo, $default = 'N/A') 

{
   return ( isset($_POST[$moreaboutgeneralinfo]) && !empty($_POST[$moreaboutgeneralinfo]) ) ? $_POST[$moreaboutgeneralinfo] : $default;
}
     $infoonboundarywalltype = post('infoonboundarywalltype');

function post($infoonboundarywalltype, $default = 'N/A') 

{
   return ( isset($_POST[$infoonboundarywalltype]) && !empty($_POST[$infoonboundarywalltype]) ) ? $_POST[$infoonboundarywalltype] : $default;
}
         $moreaboutpropertygeneralinformation = post('MoreInfoPropertyGeneralInformation');

     function post($moreaboutpropertygeneralinformation, $default = 'N/A') 

{
   return ( isset($_POST[$moreaboutpropertygeneralinformation]) && !empty($_POST[$moreaboutpropertygeneralinformation]) ) ? $_POST[$moreaboutpropertygeneralinformation] : $default;
}
     $infoaboutconsmaterial =   post('infoaboutconsmaterial');

     function post($infoaboutconsmaterial, $default = 'N/A') 

{
   return ( isset($_POST[$infoaboutconsmaterial]) && !empty($_POST[$infoaboutconsmaterial]) ) ? $_POST[$infoaboutconsmaterial] : $default;
}
     $otherinfoaboutbuildingslabs = post('otherinfoaboutbuildingslabs');

     function post($otherinfoaboutbuildingslabs, $default = 'N/A') 

{
   return ( isset($_POST[$otherinfoaboutbuildingslabs]) && !empty($_POST[$otherinfoaboutbuildingslabs]) ) ? $_POST[$otherinfoaboutbuildingslabs] : $default;
}
     $infoaboutfloors = post('infoaboutfloors'); 

     function post($infoaboutfloors, $default = 'N/A') 

{
   return ( isset($_POST[$infoaboutfloors]) && !empty($_POST[$infoaboutfloors]) ) ? $_POST[$infoaboutfloors] : $default;
}
     $infoaboutentrance = post('infoaboutentrance');

     function post($infoaboutentrance, $default = 'N/A') 

{
   return ( isset($_POST[$infoaboutentrance]) && !empty($_POST[$infoaboutentrance]) ) ? $_POST[$infoaboutentrance] : $default;
}
     $infoaboutrooms = post('infoaboutrooms');

     function post($infoaboutrooms, $default = 'N/A') 

{
   return ( isset($_POST[$infoaboutrooms]) && !empty($_POST[$infoaboutrooms]) ) ? $_POST[$infoaboutrooms] : $default;
}
     $infoaboutbuilding = post('infoaboutbuilding');

     function post($infoaboutbuilding, $default = 'N/A') 

{
   return ( isset($_POST[$infoaboutbuilding]) && !empty($_POST[$infoaboutbuilding]) ) ? $_POST[$infoaboutbuilding] : $default;
}
     $infoaboutavailibleitemhome = post('infoaboutavailibleitemhome');

     function post($infoaboutavailibleitemhome, $default = 'N/A') 

{
   return ( isset($_POST[$infoaboutavailibleitemhome]) && !empty($_POST[$infoaboutavailibleitemhome]) ) ? $_POST[$infoaboutavailibleitemhome] : $default;
}
     $propertycondition = post('propertycondition');

     function post($propertycondition, $default = 'N/A') 

{
   return ( isset($_POST[$propertycondition]) && !empty($_POST[$propertycondition]) ) ? $_POST[$propertycondition] : $default;
}
     $AdditionalInformation = post('AdditionalInformation');

     function post($AdditionalInformation, $default = 'N/A') 

{
   return ( isset($_POST[$AdditionalInformation]) && !empty($_POST[$AdditionalInformation]) ) ? $_POST[$AdditionalInformation] : $default;
}
require('../db.php');
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo 'Your Session Is Not Set.';
}
else
{

$ImageID = uniqid();

$emptyresult = array();
$emptyresult['dealername'] = 'Dealer Name';
$emptyresult['dealerfname']='Dealer Father Name';
$emptyresult['dealeroccupation']='Dealer Occupation';
$emptyresult['dealerphone']='Dealer Phone';
$emptyresult['dealeremail']='Dealer Email';
$emptyresult['dealeraddress']='Dealer Address';
$emptyresult['ownername']='Owner Name';
$emptyresult['propertytype']='Property Type';
$emptyresult['PropertyDocumentType']='Property Document Type'; 
$emptyresult['propertydealtype']='Property Deal Type';
$emptyresult['currencytype']='Currency Type';
$emptyresult['prepostedprice']='Preposted Price';
$emptyresult['priceperarea']='Price Per Area';
$emptyresult['dealstatus']='Deal Status';
$emptyresult['propertystreet']='Property Street'; 
$emptyresult['propertyregion']='Property Region';
$emptyresult['PropertyArea']='Property Area';
$emptyresult['propertydistanceamount']='Property Distance Amount'; 
$emptyresult['boundarywall']='Boundary Wall'; 
$emptyresult['boundraywalltype']='Boundary Wall Type';  
$emptyresult['streetroad']='Street Road';
$emptyresult['plot']='Plot'; 
$emptyresult['constructionmethod']='Construction Method'; 
$emptyresult['constructionmaterial']='Construction Material';
$emptyresult['buildingslabs']='Building Slabs';  
$emptyresult['floors']='Floors';  
$emptyresult['buildingentrance']='Building Entrance';  
$emptyresult['entrancetype']='Entrance Type'; 
$emptyresult['numberrooms']='Number of Rooms'; 
$emptyresult['windowtype']='Windows Type'; 
$emptyresult['corridors']='Corridors';
$emptyresult['numberandtypekittchen']='Number and Type of Kitchen';
$emptyresult['numberandtypebathroom']='Number and Type of Bathroom';
$emptyresult['itemshome']='Items at Home';  
$emptyresult['yard']='Yard';   
$emptyresult['yardconstructionmethod']='Yard Construction Method';
$emptyresult['maingatenumber']='Main Gate Number';  
$emptyresult['garage']='Garage';  
$emptyresult['utilities']='Utilities';  
$emptyresult['requirements']='Requirements'; 
$emptyresult['underconstruction']='Under Construction';



foreach($emptyresult as $key => $val) {
   if (empty($_POST[$key])) {
      echo "You Have Not Entered Any Value For <b>( $val )</b> <br>";
   }
}

        $errors = array();

    if (empty($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['name'][0])) 

    {
    $errors[] = '-You have\'nt Entered Value for upload field'; 
    }

   else 
    {

    if (count($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['name']) !== 6)
        $errors[] = "-Your Only Allowed Six Images";


    $whitelist = array("jpg","png","JPG","PNG");

    foreach($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['name'] as $file) 
    {
        if ($file) 
        { 

            $temp = explode('.', $file);

            if (!in_array(end($temp), $whitelist )) 

            {
                $errors[] = "-All images must be JPG or PNG<br>";
                break;

            }
        }
    }
}

if (!empty($errors))
  {
    foreach ($errors as $e)
        echo $e."<br/>";
        exit();
  }
    if(empty($_POST['drop_1']))
    {
         echo '-You hav\'nt Select Your Province<br>';
    }
    if(empty($_POST['drop_2']))
    {
         echo '-You hav\'nt Select Your District<br>';
    }
    if(empty($_POST['drop_3']))
    {
         echo '-You hav\'nt Select Your PD(Nahya)<br><br>';
         exit();
    }
  else
  {

     $propertydealername = $_POST['dealername'];
     $propertydealerfname = $_POST['dealerfname'];
     $propertydealeroccupation = $_POST['dealeroccupation'];
     $propertydealerphone = $_POST['dealerphone'];
     $propertydealeremail = $_POST['dealeremail'];
     $propertydealeraddress = $_POST['dealeraddress'];

     $propertyownername = $_POST['ownername'];
     $propertyownerfname = $_POST['ownerfname'];
     $propertyowneroccupation = $_POST['owneroccupation'];
     $propertyownerphone = $_POST['ownerphone'];
     $propertyowneremail = $_POST['owneremail'];
     $propertyowneraddress = $_POST['owneraddress'];

     $propertytype = $_POST['propertytype']; 
     $PropertyDocument= $_POST['PropertyDocumentType'];
     $propertydealtype  = $_POST['propertydealtype'];
     $currencytype  = $_POST['currencytype'];
     $PrepostedPrice= $_POST['prepostedprice'];
     $PricePerArea= $_POST['priceperarea'];
     $DealStatus= $_POST['dealstatus']; 
     $housenumber = $_POST['HouseNumber'];
     $propertystreet = $_POST['propertystreet']; 
     $propertyregion = $_POST['propertyregion'];
     $PD = $_POST['drop_3']; 
     $District = $_POST['drop_2']; 
     $Province = $_POST['drop_1'];
     $PropertyArea = $_POST['PropertyArea'];
     $propertyareaamount = $_POST['propertydistanceamount']; 
     $boundarywall = $_POST['boundarywall']; 
     $boundraywalltype = join(' - ', $_POST['boundraywalltype']);
     $streetroad = join(' - ', $_POST['streetroad']);
     $plot = join(' - ', $_POST['plot']); 
     $constructionmethod = join(' - ', $_POST['constructionmethod']);
     $constructionmaterial = join(' - ', $_POST['constructionmaterial']);
     $buildingslabs = join(' - ', $_POST['buildingslabs']);
     $floors =join(' - ', $_POST['floors']);
     $buildingentrance = join(' - ', $_POST['buildingentrance']);
     $entrancetype = $_POST['entrancetype']; 
     $numberrooms = $_POST['numberrooms'];
     $windowtype =  join(' - ', $_POST['windowtype']);
     $corridors = join(' - ', $_POST['corridors']);
     $numberandtypekittchen = join(' - ', $_POST['numberandtypekittchen']);
     $numberandtypebathroom = join(' - ', $_POST['numberandtypebathroom']);
     $itemshome = join(' - ', $_POST['itemshome']);
     $yard = join(' - ', $_POST['yard']);
     $yardconstructionmethod = join(' - ', $_POST['yardconstructionmethod']);
     $maingatenumber = join(' - ', $_POST['maingatenumber']);
     $garage = $_POST['garage'];
     $utilities = join(' - ', $_POST['utilities']);
     $requirements = join(' - ', $_POST['requirements']);
     $files=$_FILES['Upload_Property_Images'];
     $underconstruction = $_POST['underconstruction'];



$query = "INSERT INTO `properties` 
(`PropertyDealerName`,
  `PropertyDealerFName`,
    `PropertyDealerOccupation`,
     `PropertyDealerPhone`,
      `PropertyDealerEmail`,
       `PropertyDealerAddress`,
        `PropertyOwnerName`,
         `PropertyOwnerFName`,
          `PropertyOwnerOccupation`,
           `PropertyOwnerPhone`,
            `PropertyOwnerEmail`,
             `PropertyOwnerAddress`,
`ImageID`,
  `PropertyType`,
   `PropertyDocument`,
    `PropertyDealType`,
     `CurrencyType`,
      `PropostedPrice`,
       `PricePerArea`,
        `DealStatus`,
         `MoreinfoDealGeneralInformation`,
          `HouseNumber`,
          `PropertyStreet`,
           `PropertyRegion`,
            `PDID`,
             `DistrictID`,
              `ProvinceID`,
                 `PropertyArea`,
                  `PropertyAreaAmount`,
                   `PropertyBoundaryWall`,
                    `PropertyBoundaryWallType`,
                     `MoreInfoOnBoundaryWall`,
                      `PropertyRoadStreet`,
                       `PropertyPlot`,
                        `MoreInfoPropertyGeneralInformation`,
                         `PropertyConstructionMethod`,
                          `PropertyConstructionMaterial`,
                           `MoreInfoOnConstructionMaterial`,
                            `PropertyBuildingSlabs`,
                             `MoreInfoOnBuildingSlabs`,
                              `PropertyFloors`,
                               `MoreInfoOnPropertyFlooers`,
                                `PropertyBuildingEntrance`,
                                 `MoreInfoOnPropertyEntrance`,
                                  `PropertyBuildingEntranceType`,
                                   `PropertyRoomNumbers`,
                                    `MoreInfoOnPropertyRooms`,
                                     `PropertyWindowsType`,
                                      `PropertyCorridors`,
                                       `PropertyKitchensNumberType`,
                                        `PropertyBathroomsNumType`,
                                         `PropertyAvailiableItemsRooms`,
                                          `MoreInfobuilding`,
                                           `PropertyYard`,
                                            `PropertyYardConstructionMethod`,
                                             `PropertyMainGateNumber`,
                                              `Garage`,
                                               `MoreInfoYard`,
                                                `PropertyUtilities`,
                                                 `PropertyGeneralCondition`,
                                                  `PropertyRequirements`,
                                                   `AdditionalInformation`,
                                                      `UnderConstruction`)
VALUES
('$propertydealername',
'$propertydealerfname',
'$propertydealeroccupation',
'$propertydealerphone',
'$propertydealeremail',
'$propertydealeraddress',
'$propertyownername',
'$propertyownerfname',
'$propertyowneroccupation',
'$propertyownerphone',
'$propertyowneremail',
'$propertyowneraddress',
'$ImageID',
'$propertytype',
'$PropertyDocument',
'$propertydealtype',
'$currencytype',
'$PrepostedPrice',
'$PricePerArea',
'$DealStatus',
'$moreaboutgeneralinfo',
'$housenumber',
'$propertystreet',
'$propertyregion',
'$PD',
'$District',
'$Province',
'$PropertyArea',
'$propertyareaamount',
'$boundarywall',
'$boundraywalltype',
'$infoonboundarywalltype',
'$streetroad',
'$plot',
'$moreaboutpropertygeneralinformation',
'$constructionmethod',
'$constructionmaterial',
'$infoaboutconsmaterial',
'$buildingslabs',
'$otherinfoaboutbuildingslabs',
'$floors', 
'$infoaboutfloors',
'$buildingentrance',
'$infoaboutentrance',
'$entrancetype',
'$numberrooms',
'$infoaboutrooms',
'$windowtype',
'$corridors',
'$numberandtypekittchen',
'$numberandtypebathroom',
'$itemshome',
'$infoaboutavailibleitemhome',
'$yard',
'$yardconstructionmethod',
'$maingatenumber',
'$garage',
'$infoaboutbuilding',
'$utilities',
'$propertycondition',
'$requirements',
'$AdditionalInformation',
'$underconstruction');";

     $queryrun = $connection->query($query); 
     if( $connection->error ) exit( $connection->error );

     if($queryrun) 
     {
         echo 'The Form With Below Images Has Been Inserted Successfully<br><br>';
     }
     else
     {
         echo 'Sorry Query Failed';
     }






    // start code for the insertion of the images.

    if (empty($errors)) 
    {
        foreach ($_FILES as $file) 
        {

    mkdir("PropertyImages/$ImageID");   
    for($x = 0; $x < count($files['name']); $x++)
    {
      $name=$files['name'][$x];
      $tmp_name=$files['tmp_name'][$x];
         if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "PropertyImages/$ImageID/".$name))
         {

             $imagequery="INSERT INTO propertyimages(ImageID, ImageName, ImagePath) VALUES('$ImageID', '$name', 'PropertyImages/$ImageID/$name')";
             $imagequeryrun=$connection->query($imagequery);
             if( $connection->error ) exit( $connection->error );
             echo 'Image <b>'. $name .'</b> Uploaded Successfully <br><br>';

         }

    }
            }
    }   
}

    $subject = 'SPdealers Group';
    $message = 'Your Property has been received we are going for verification of your property and during this process we are calling you for further information. Thanks SPdealers Group.';

    mail($propertydealeremail,$subject,$message,"From: contact@spdealers.com");
    echo "Please Check Your Email Address.";
}
```

Comment: Try put the function at the top of the file and let me know what happens then.

Comment: There are hundreds of `function post` in your code, why so?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky: Cos i have hundreds of fields

Comment: Take the function `post()` out to the `if-else` condition block. In addition, it is enough if you define only one function. There is no need to create a new one for each form input.

Answer (score 0):

You defined `post()` after you used it. Define it at the beginning of the script and this error shouldn't appear anymore.

```
$moreaboutgeneralinfo = post('moreaboutgeneralinfo'); // <-- Used it here

function post($moreaboutgeneralinfo, $default = 'N/A') // <-- Defined here
{
   return ( isset($_POST[$moreaboutgeneralinfo]) && !empty($_POST[$moreaboutgeneralinfo]) ) ? $_POST[$moreaboutgeneralinfo] : $default;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to define the function before it is used. You can define it anywhere. No matter

Comment: @Hanky PHP *does* mind if the function definition is conditional (i.e. inside an `if`).

Comment: I can attest to deceze's comment. I was unaware of that too before I learnt it the hard way

Comment: @Y U NO WORK: i have put the functtions at the top but still getting this error "
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare post() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\SPdealer\Admin Panel\Property_Insertion_Files\Customers Online Property_Insert_Page_exe .php:4) in C:\xampp\htdocs\SPdealer\Admin Panel\Property_Insertion_Files\Customers Online Property_Insert_Page_exe .php on line 15"

Comment: @user3724705 Yes, thats the problem which Hanky mentioned. You cannot redeclare functions. Functions are there to make your life easier, so you only declare them once and then you can use them anytime with your arguments.